How is it possible for a glm and an emmeans on the same model to get different results?
I'm running a model comparing percent abnormality across two factors, mate pair and treatment. I ran the code:
model <- glm(Percent~Treatment+MatePair, data=sub_plut_abnorm)  summary(model)
enter image description here
I got a p value of .0426 at treatment level 100ppb, implying it was different from the control. Then, I ran the following code:
em <- emmeans(subplut1, ~Treatment)
contrast(em, "pairwise", adjust = "Tukey")
enter image description here
However, it found no significant differences between any of the treatments and the control. Does anyone know what that means?
I've researched different ways to run the emmeans() function, but either they don't seem relevant or they output the same results.
